How do I add IronPython Interpreter in PyCharm?
I'm working with some API's that require IronPython and I use JetBrains' Pycharm to code. The only problem is that, after formatting my PC, I can't add the IronPython 3.4 interpreter to it.
I tried adding it as a Virtualenv and a System Interpreter, but both yield "Select Python Interpreter\n An invalid Python interpreter name 'ipy.exe'!"
I've already searched online, read documentation, but nothing seems to work... and it was working fine before formatting

Just renamed the "ipy.exe" to "IronPython3.4.exe" and it worked. I had to add as a System Interpreter though, not Virtualenv.
